# Select records from mysql database where expiry date is in date_time and epoch format

Tags: php, mysql

Need to run cron to determine about to expire records in 2 days (48 hours) and not less than 1 day (24 hours) to make sure it doesn't select records twice if cron runs every 24 hours.

The expiry date column is in date_time format in one table and in the other table it is in int datatype(unix epoch format).
Would this query work for epoch as well or I would have to convert epoch to date time in php ?

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE expiry_date < DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY) 
AND expiry_date > DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Comment: The simple way to find that out would be to run it and find out for yourself.

Comment: In future, always show us the schema for any tables you are talking about in a question, along with some sample data and a view of what you want the output to be